# Maximum Number of arraylist is only 99999999

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Dim totalAllArr(99999999) As Integer
Public Sub SynchNow()
    ListOfBooksTableAdapter.Fill(OJT_Project_LSDataSet.ListOfBooks)
    For i = 0 To all - 1
        totalAllArr(i) = OJT_Project_LSDataSet.Tables("ListOfBooks").Rows(i).Item("numberofcopy")
        totalAll = totalAll + totalAllArr(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

I use this code for counting the sum of all books stored in ListOfBooks table

'this one works

Dim totalAllArr(99999999) As Integer

'this one doesn't work

Dim totalAllArr() As Integer

so the maximum bounds of array may store only 99999999 value
if the number of books exceeds, sure it will throw exception

any other structure of array may use? Please!

Comment: Why do you need the array? You can just find the sum without having an array at all. Also note that an array isn't the same as an ArrayList.

Comment: I have to because the fieldname numberofcopy has its each value so I have to store it first in array

Comment: I don't follow you at all. What do you think would go wrong if you just used `totalAll = totalAll + OJT_Project_LSDataSet.Tables("ListOfBooks").Rows(i).Item("numberofcopy")`?

Comment: thanks! i'm gonna try it.

Comment: hey wait,
the problem is in array.
the computation is working.

Comment: Exactly - if you just need the total, you don't *need* the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ArrayList` or generic `List` instead:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList Lst1 = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
```

or

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> Lst2 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
```